# Thread stops working in sleep mode

Tags: android, multithreading, uiview

I am updating a counter in thread and its working fine.
But when the phone is in sleep and activity runs after aquiring wakelock, the thread not updates the UI using counter.

Here is my function where I am updating the view value.

```
private void updateTimeInBackground() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startAlarm();
            int counter = MINUTE;
            // in this function Im using the runOnUiThread(...) to update the view and also used TextView.post(...)
            updateTextViewValue(counter);

            if (isDismissed)
                return;
            updateOverlayForAlert();

            counter = 0;
            int minutes = 1;
            vibrator.vibrate(1000);
            // in this function Im using the runOnUiThread(...) to update the view and also used TextView.post(...)
            updateTextViewValue(counter, minutes);
        }
    }).start();
```

Any suggestions? or hint?

Comment: do not use an activity. If you anything to happen after the phone goes to sleep mode you should use a `service`.

Comment: @Budius, i have to show something to user.

Comment: Not after the phone goes to sleep mode.

Comment: i m using service to track the event in the background and then calling an Activity from the Service

Comment: update ui in UiThread

Answer (score -1):

Use `TimerTask` which will continue to run in the background.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why this is down voted? Using timertask for updating time purpose is the good solution.

Comment: If we change date or time, it will stop or run continuously.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Handler` and `Runnable` instead of `Thread`

```
 final Handler handler=new Handler();

runnable=new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);


        // your code
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

Comment: i think the Handler is used to post the message on the UI thread. This wont be the answer.